# for loop within a try block

Tags: java, exception

If a `for` loop exists within a `try` block, and during one of the iteration of the `for` loop, an exception is thrown, does the remaining iterations of the `for` loop continue, or is it completely aborted?

```
try{
  for(...){
   //throws exception during one of the iteration
  }
}catch(Exception e){
 ....
}
```

The doubt is in reference to a programming question I have been trying to solve where we model a car rental service.
In the fixed uneditable  code given in the question (see below), we run a `for` loop to iterate over car rental requests recieved (and create an object `obj` for each request).
The function call `obj.carBooker()` has one task of printing how much each passenger pays (totat fare for the destination/head count). It should throw appropriate checked exception - `ImproperHeadCountException`: if no. of passengers provided is less than 1, `WrongDestinationException`: if the destination provided is not in our database which has been stored in a hash map.

```
    int num = s.nextInt(); //input the number of car rental requests
    try {
        for(int i=1;i<=num;i++) {
            int heads = s.nextInt(); //enter head count of passengers
            s.nextLine();  //enter destination
            String dest = s.nextLine();     
            CarRental obj = new CarRental(heads,dest);
            obj.carBooker();
        }
    }catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getCause());
    }
```

A sample input for the problem is:

```
3
0
Marina Beach
4
Elliot's Beach
5
Taj Mahal
```

My problem is that in my solution code, where I have to implement the carBooker() method, the `for` loop aborts the moment it catches the first exception for a given car rental request and doesn't proceeds to other requests. Due to this,  my actual output comes as,
`ImproperHeadCountException: Head count should be positive non zero value\n`

whereas the expected output is

```
ImproperHeadCountException: Head count should be positive non zero value 
Destination: Elliot's Beach, Head cost: 1250.0 
WrongDestinationException: Invalid destination
```

It doesn't iterate through the other two car rental requests.

My code is as below

```
public void carBooker() throws ArithmeticException, NullPointerException{
    //define this method according to the problem description
    try{
        if (this.passenger_count < 1){
            throw new ArithmeticException();
        }
        double fare_per_head = available_destinations.get(this.chosen_destination)/this.passenger_count;
        System.out.println("Destination: " + this.chosen_destination + ", " + "Head cost:" + fare_per_head);
    }catch(NullPointerException e){
            WrongDestinationException newe = new WrongDestinationException();
            e.initCause(newe);
            throw e;
    }catch(ArithmeticException e_){
            ImproperHeadCountException newe_ = new ImproperHeadCountException();
            e_.initCause(newe_);
            throw e_;            
    } 
}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: " does the remaining iterations of the for loop continue, or is it completely aborted?"  Yes it is immediately aborted.  If you do not want the loop aborted you need to `catch` _inside_ of the loop body.

Comment: If you want the loop to complete, you'll have to put the try/catch block inside the loop.  You'll need a collection or some data structure outside the loop scope so you can hang onto the error data and act on it after the loop is completed.

Comment: Java exceptions have ['termination semantics'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exception_handling#Termination_and_resumption_semantics).  There's no mechanism to carry on either 'exactly where you left off' or 'some place else such as the next execution of the loop'.  All that context is **gone** by the time the exception handler gets control. Think about the case where the try-catch is not even in the same method as the for-loop.

Answer (score 0):

Problem with your code is that you have try/catch outside of for loop, so when an exception is thrown, your application won't crash, but the for loop would not iterate over another iteration.

In this particular code, you want to put the try/catch inside of the for loop, so whenever there is an exception thrown during your iteration, it will catch it and continue with another iteration.

So, your code should look like this:

```
for (...){
     try{
         //throws exception during one of the iteration
     } catch(Exception e) {
     ....
     }
}
```